# Is there standard notation for the projection out of an indexed coproduct?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, category-theory

Let $X : I \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ denote an $I$-indexed family of sets. Then the indexed coproduct of $X$ has a projection $$\bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i \rightarrow I$$ that tells us which $i \in I$ our element in the coproduct corresponds to. This makes the coproduct into a slice over $I$; in differential geometry, it tends to make it into a bundle. This features in the definition of the underlying total space of the Whitney sum of vector bundles, for example.

> **Question.** This seems to show up a lot, especially in differential geometry. Is there anything approaching accepted notation for this function, like $\pi_X$ or something like that?

Comment: If you consider the elements of a coproduct (disjoint union) as $(i, x_i)$ where $i\in I, x_i\in X_i$ then you could denote it by $\pi_1$ (because you project on the first component) or $\pi_I$. But as far as i know there is no general notation for this.

Comment: Some variation on $\pi$ or $p$ is usually used. This is not surprising as set theoretically or type theoretically, $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}X_i$ is a kind of pair type. Indeed, $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}X$ is $I\times X$, so, in this case, the relevant projection is literally $\pi_1$. In dependently typed proof assistants, it's not unusual for pairs to be *defined* as a special case of dependent sum leading to the projection you are talking about and $\pi_1$ being identical.